# htaccess - Hide all URL leave just domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vs/shop/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /shop/home[L]
```

What this piece of code does is when the user open the url: domain.com it redirects the user to domain.com/shop/home BUT in the url bar it only shows domain.com

This works for the homepage. The problem is I have 100 pages and I won't do it manually.

How can I make this script dynamic?

What I mean is:

I want to the address bar (the URL bar) to display only: domain.com and not domain.com/shop/home or domain.com/shop/pages or domain.com/shop/etc

Am I specific enough?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? please be specific

Comment: Updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

You need to Reorder your rules and add a L flag to end the rule proccessing

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /shop/home [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vs/shop/$1 [L]
```